# Adding images to jQuery Tags Input plugin

Tags: jquery, input

I'm working on an input field for a list of recipients which will show avatars when the recipient is added.

I'm using the [jQuery Tags Input Plugin](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) so that users can enter multiple recipients, separated by commas.

When the callback function onAddTag is called it replaces the text in the tag with the avatar and then the value. However, when the user presses backspace or removes the tag the avatar is removed from all of the recipients. Any ideas how I should change my onAddTag function to keep the avatars loaded?

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ez5rrute/) and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#recipients').tagsInput({
        'height': 'auto',
        'width': 'auto',
        'defaultText': 'Add a tag',
        'onAddTag': function(elem, elem_tags) {
            $('.tag', elem_tags).each(function() {
                var username = $(this).text();
                username = username.replace('x', '');
                username = username.replace(/\s/g, '');
                $(this).html('<img src="https://minotar.net/helm/' + username + '/16" alt="' + username + '"> ' + $(this).text());
            });
        },
        'minChars' : 3,
        'maxChars' : 16
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of the jQuery Tags Input plugin re-renders *all* tags after any one of them is deleted. You can test that yourself by using your JS Console or Developer Tools to edit one of the tags, then hit backspace to delete another tag and you'll see the original restored.

To get around that, I think the best option the plugin allows would be to use the `onChange` callback for adding avatars instead of `onAddTag`. That way, your avatar-inserting function will be called every time the tags are re-rendered, whether it's caused by adding or removing a tag!